# External HDD not working, not showing any partition to mount

Tags: filesystems, partition, external-hdd

HDD model: Western Digital My Passport 25E2 4TB filesystem NTFS

Yesterday it was working, now when I plug it in `lsblk` doesn't show any partition to mount, just this:

```
sdb                  8:16   0   3.6T  0 disk
```

```
$ smartctl -a /dev/sdb:
Read Device Identity failed: empty IDENTIFY data

A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

```
$ journalctl -f
kernel: ses 5:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
kernel: ses 5:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
kernel: .............ready
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 7813969920 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 timing out command, waited 180s
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=180s
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Internal target failure
kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
kernel: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
```

The unit doesn't appear on `fdisk -l` and on a Windows machine it appears as not initialized and showing an hardware error when trying to initialize with right click

Comment: The errors indicate it's dead, Jim. Hopefully no data is lost and you've got backups.